# Obtain culprit from Sentry event in PHP

Tags: php, sentry

I'm trying to filter the events the PHP application sends to sentry by defining

```
'before_send' => function (\Sentry\Event $event) { }
```

I get the `$event` object all right, but I can't find a way to get `culprit` or `location` information that I can see at sentry report (altered screenshot of json data they store about the event attached).

Unfortunately, their documentation is not very helpful - or at least I was not able to find correct methods to obtain any of those 2 pieces.

Any ideas on what I'm missing? Looping through the frames doesn't look like a correct approach in my case.

[image: partial screenshot from sentry's json file]

Comment: Hi there, the culprit and location is not a concept [known by the SDK](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/blob/4f6f8fa701e5db53c04f471b139e7d4f85831f17/src/Serializer/PayloadSerializer.php#L35-L164), those values are generated server side when the event is ingested. For the culprit [see here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/blob/ce898db90cf0a79ef3ec9991683bccdfaf8c693b/src/sentry/culprit.py#L15-L40). I could not find the location source code quickly but it's probably just looking though the stack frames finding the first in-app frame and using the location of that (that's a guess).

Comment: It might be useful to you to know in the latest version of the PHP SDK you also get the `EventHint` which contains the actual `Throwable` which might be of use to you: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/configuration/filtering/#event-hints.

Comment: @AlexBouma, thank you for your comments. When I call `$event->getTransaction()` from before_send handler I am getting `NULL`, need to look at the latest version for `EventHint`

Comment: The transaction is being set by a [integration](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/blob/bfab90c7ef921221b52b75b5108201e87f0f4661/src/Integration/TransactionIntegration.php#L26-L46). I can't tell much from your story about your environment. If you are using a framework integration (Laravel/Symfony) or just plain `sentry/sdk` in your application. But assuming a plain PHP app you might not use `\Sentry\init()` to init the SDK or `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` is not set (certainly possible if it's a CLI app or cronjob or something) or disabled the default integrations which include the transaction.

Comment: @AlexBouma, I have symfony-like framework, and using sentry/sdk package from composer. before_send is a callback which gets called when (and if) an error happened, so $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is for sure set. But even at the moment I'm calling \Sentry\init() the app is fully loaded.

It looks like parsing through frames is the most correct approach. It is strange that culprit is not generated on the client, but present on server.

Comment: Sentry is a pretty cool piece of kit so it makes sense that the culprit is "calculated" by the server for a few reasons. The SDK need to implement much less common code, can all be implemented on the server. Not too relevant for PHP but for example in JavaScript it can retrieve sourcemaps and with much more accuracy determine a good cullprit. You can even have custom rules to change the culprit server side. The SDK just send everything they have and let the server do the heavy lifting of finding out what it just got.